# Strange behaviour for proxy when two abstract classes are passed in

Tags: clojure

I know this is a silly example but I am curious to know what is happening with the proxy method.

I have set up two calls to proxy:

1.
  (def cp
    (proxy [java.util.AbstractMap clojure.asm.ClassVisitor] []))

2.
  (def cp
    (proxy [clojure.asm.ClassVisitor java.util.AbstractMap] []))

The first call is fine.... and it return cp.  The second call gives me an exception.

clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class, compiling:(/private/var/folders/dd/qfdy6sbn3mlgk20vcxc3j0ljnpxsqr/T/form-init4780219965491827451.clj:2:5)
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
                                        java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1         ClassLoader.java
                                         java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass         ClassLoader.java:  800
                                         java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass         ClassLoader.java:  643
                               clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.defineClass  DynamicClassLoader.java:   46
                                              clojure.core/get-proxy-class           core_proxy.clj:  262

What is happening underneath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither will work in Clojure 1.6.0. In 1.5, `clojure.asm.ClassVisitor` was an interface instead of an abstract class. Proxy expects at most one class followed by optional interfaces. As `java.util.AbstractMap` is an abstract class, it cannot appear second in the list of class-and-interfaces.